# Self-Contained Proof that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^p}$ Converges for $p > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

To prove the convergence of the p-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^p}$$

for $p > 1$, one typically appeals to either the Integral Test or the Cauchy Condensation Test.

I am wondering if there is a self-contained proof that this series converges which does not rely on either test.

I suspect that any proof would have to use the ideas behind one of these two tests.

Answer (score 348, accepted):

We can bound the partial sums by multiples of themselves:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
S_{2k+1}
&=&
\sum_{n=1}^{2k+1}\frac{1}{n^p}\\
&=&
1+\sum_{i=1}^k\left(\frac{1}{(2i)^p}+\frac{1}{(2i+1)^p}\right)\\
&<&1+\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{2}{(2i)^p}\\
&=&1+2^{1-p}S_k\\
&<&1+2^{1-p}S_{2k+1}\;.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Then solving for $S_{2k+1}$ yields

$$S_{2k+1}<\frac{1}{1-2^{1-p}}\;,$$

and since the sequence of partial sums is monotonically increasing and bounded from above, it converges.

---

Eight years after I posted this, [Zach Teitler](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/343280/zach-teitler) pointed out that this proof was already published in $1979$ by [Teresa Cohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teresa_Cohen) and [William J. Knight](https://clas.iusb.edu/computer-science-informatics/people/faculty/Knight.html) in *Convergence and Divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^p$*, Mathematics Magazine, $52(3)$, $1979$, p. $178$ ([accessible version](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690283), [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1080/0025570X.1979.11976778)).

Comment: +1 Nice.  Where did you see this first?  I was about to write a proof I used in an undergraduate course, but it only works for powers being the natural numbers.

Comment: @Glen: I never saw this; I just made it up when I saw the question :-)

Comment: @joriki: Great.  I wonder how good your bound is?  I posted the answer I had written up anyway, since I figure *maybe* somebody would find it useful, although yours is far superior ;).

Comment: @Glen: Your proof is good to know, too. Concerning how good the bound is: For $p\to\infty$, it becomes exact, directly yielding the limit of $1$. For $p\to1^+$, we can get the asymptotic behaviour by approximating the sum by an integral, which gives $S_k\to1/(p-1)$, whereas my bound becomes $S_k<1/(\ln 2 (p-1))$, so it's a factor of $1/\ln 2\approx1.44$ off; I presume for $p$ between these extremes the factor will take on the values in between.

Comment: This is a really slick proof.  I get a glimpse of the Condensation Test in it, but some students might like this argument better.

Comment: @Glen @Joriki See the crude lower bound in my post.

Comment: @Didier @Glen: Interesting -- so my proof and the condensation test  yield the same upper bound.

Comment: @Glen @Joriki @Pete Call $S_o$ the sum of the odd numbered terms $x_{2n+1}$ and $S_e$ he sum of the even numbered terms $x_{2n}$. Joriki's proof is based on three facts: (1) $S=S_o+S_e$, (2) $S_o\le x_1+S_e$ and (3) $S_e=2^{-p}S$. Now, (1) is always true, (2) follows from the fact (4) that $(x_n)$ is nonincreasing, and (3) follows from the fact (5) that $x_{2n}=2^{-p}x_n$. The proof based on the decomposition into slabs that I explained, known as Cauchy's condensation test for slabs $C_k$ of length $2^k$ is based on the following: .../...

Comment: .../... $C_k$ is at most twice the sum of the even numbered terms $x_n$ in it, this is fact (4), and for $k\ge1$ this latter sum is $2^{-p}C_{k-1}$, this is fact (5), and $C_0=x_1$. So, I would say that both proofs are based on facts (4) and (5) and use them a little differently. A final remark: one can compare Joriki's technique based on congruences modulo $3$ and Cauchy's condensation for slabs associated to the sequence $(3^k)$. Then (I think) the former yields $S\le(1+2^{-p})/(1-3^{1-p})$ and the latter yields $S\le2/(1-3^{1-p})$, so the coincidence disappears.

Comment: @Joriki By the way, your method *is* a condensation test, only based on the sequence $2k$ instead of $2^k$ or $3^k$. I should have pointed it before but am a bit slow today...

Comment: @Didier: True -- but the question only excluded the Cauchy condensation test, not condensation tests in general :-) Though I guess this would still qualify as "using the ideas behind one of these two tests"...

Comment: @joriki: Right. I realize that I called Cauchy condensation tests what is really a generalization... and that I ought not to.

Comment: @joriki: This is great. When I teach Calc II, I teach series before integration. (It gets the hardest stuff out of the way first.) But, that means I can't use the integral test, which is most often used for p-series. With your proof in hand, I don't need the integral test at all!

Comment: @Jim: Glad to be of service :-)

Comment: @Jim: That was partially the motivation behind the question.

Comment: @joriki:  Thanks for this very nice proof.  My first impression is that it is not simply a condensation test based on $2k$ instead of $2^k$.  A similar idea is there, but it seems a bit different.  Your proof seems to use the definition of this particular series critically to make an nice simplification.  Your proof does not seem to be Schlömilch's condensation test with $n_k = 2k$ in disguise.

Comment: Schlömilch's condensation test says that if $a_n$ is a nonnegative and decreasing sequence, then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \text{ converges} \qquad \text{if and only if} \qquad  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (n_{k+1} - n_{k}) a_{n_k} \text{ converges}
$$
where $n_k$ is any strictly increasing sequence of positive integers such that
$$
\frac{n_{k+1} - n_{k}}{n_{k} - n_{k-1}}
$$
is bounded.  Note that Cauchy's condensation test takes $n_k = 2^k$.

Comment: Very nice proof. You can you use the same kind of trick to extend the $\zeta$ function on the critical strip by checking that $(1-2^s) \, \zeta(s) = \eta(s)$ where the Dirichlet $\eta$ function is defined by $\eta(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}$.

Comment: May I ask, you have only proven that the subsequence $S_{2k+1}$ is bounded, but we can't conclude from that that the sequence $S_{k}$ is bounded, can we?

Comment: @MichalDvořák "since the sequence of partial sums is monotonically increasing" $$S_{2k+1}<\frac{1}{1-2^{1-p}}$$ implies $$S_k<\frac{1}{1-2^{1-p}}$$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Could someone please explain how we got from $$\sum_{n=1}^{2k+1}\frac{1}{n^p}$$ to $$1 + \sum_{i=1}^k (\frac{1}{(2i)^p} + \frac{1}{(2i + 1)^p} ) $$?

Comment: @Patrick just break the summation $$\sum_{n=1}^{2k+1}\frac{1}{n^p}$$ into terms like $$1+\left(\frac{1}{2^p}+\frac{1}{3^p}\right)+...+\left(\frac{1}{(2k)^p}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)^p}\right)$$.

Comment: removed. thanks, I really appreciate your help

Comment: @GlenWheeler: You asked where I first saw this. In the meantime, Zach Teitler pointed out a paper with this proof from $1979$ (see the edited answer).

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip: From the number of upvotes this answer has accumulated over the years, I suspect you refer to it in your Calc II course? :-) See the edited answer for a reference to a $1979$ paper in which this proof was apparently first published.

Comment: @joriki thanks for the reference. Actually, due to certain life changes, I haven't taught calc II in many years, but I will keep this in mind if I ever do again!

Answer (score 51):

My personal favourite is a variant of a common proof that the harmonic series diverges: we get  $$\sum_{n=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1}\frac1{n^p}\le2^k\cdot\frac1{2^{kp}}=2^{(1-p)k}.$$ because the sum has $2^k$ terms of which the first is the largest. Now sum this over $k$ to get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^p}\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{(1-p)k}=\frac1{1-2^{1-p}}<\infty$$ since $2^{1-p}<1$.

Comment: Yeah, I know I am late to this particular party, but I figured this one also deserved to be in the list of solutions.

Comment: hi, I know this question is from 2012, but I am wondering how do you get to the first line, where $\sum 1/n^p$ .... , thanks !

Comment: @MathAvengers As I explain just below that line, by multiplying the number of terms by the largest one. (The inequality is actually strict, except when $k=0$.)

Comment: I just checked: this **was** already explained on the page for roughly a year when you posted it.

Comment: @Did When I posted my answer, I clearly had not noticed the same proof buried in the fourth paragraph of your answer, or I would *at least* have made a reference to it. Sorry about that, but it really isn't obvious unless you read carefully.

Comment: Not buried in the least, sorry. And anyway, when somebody chooses to answer a question already with answers, one full year after the party is over, one could expect that they check, even minimally, the previous answers. Well, this is not a big deal, I guess, but this behaviour, which I saw several times on the site, still surprises me...

Comment: This is just the Cauchy Condensation Test

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal Indeed, that is so. Thanks for pointing it out. And now I see that the original question referred to it! In fact, if I were to teach this today, I would do the present case first, then use that to motivate the general caes of the CCT.

Answer (score 19):

FWIW, the properties of the *generalized harmonic series* $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ can be used to prove another convergence criterion (which goes under the name of *second Cauchy's convergence criterion*, as far as I remember).

The criterion is the following:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive numbers. If:
>
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln \frac{1}{a_n}}{\ln n} =L>1 \tag{1}$$
>
> then the series $\sum a_n$ converges. On the other hand, if:
>
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln \frac{1}{a_n}}{\ln n} =l<1 \tag{2}$$
>
> then the series $\sum a_n$ diverges.

The proof is very simple. The criterion remains valid even if one replaces $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}$ with $\displaystyle \liminf_{n\to \infty}$ in (1) and with $\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to \infty}$ in (2).

Comment: This is very nice.  It is an analog of the root test, whose proof relies on comparison with a geometric series.  The proof here relies on comparison with a $p$-series (i.e., a generalized harmonic series).

Answer (score 14):

This is the most direct and elementary way I know how to prove the result, although it only works for powers in the range $[0,1] \cup [2,\infty)$ which is exactly the uninteresting set, and Joriki's answer is much better regardless.  I had already written this, and perhaps somebody finds it useful.

First we consider $p=1$.  Set $x_n$ equal to the greatest power of 2 less than $\frac{1}{n}$. That is, $$(x_n) = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\dots).$$

Note that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_n
 = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{j=2^i}^{2^{i+1}-1}x_j\Big)
 = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{j=2^i}^{2^{i+1}-1} \frac{1}{2^{i+1}}\Big)
 = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2},
$$
which diverges, and that $x_n < \frac{1}{n}$, which proves $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ also diverges.

If $p = 2$, let $x_n = \frac{1}{n(n-1)} = \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}$ if $n>1$ and 1 if $n=1$.

Observe that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}\Big) = 1 + 1 - \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1/n) = 2,$$
and so in particular this series converges.

Now
$x_n > \frac{1}{n \cdot n} = \frac{1}{n^2},$
so the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$ converges as well.

Finally if $p>2$ then since $\frac{1}{n^p} < \frac{1}{n^2}$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges, and 
if $0<p<1$ we have $\frac{1}{n^p} > \frac{1}{n}$, and so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$ diverges.

Comment: This is the way I knew for the longest time, before taking a course in Real Analysis and learning the proper Techniques and Results

Answer (score 13):

For every $p>1$, one can reduce the problem to the convergence of some geometric series. Then, either one takes the latter for granted or one proves it by an elementary argument. More details below.

Let $N(k)$ denote the integer part of $a^k$, where the real number $a>1$ is defined by $a^{p-1}=2$. The sum of $1/n^p$ over $n$ between $N(k)$ and $N(k+1)$ is at most the number of terms $N(k+1)-N(k)$ times the greatest term $1/N(k)^p$. This contribution behaves like 
$$
(a^{k+1}-a^k)/a^{kp}\sim(a-1)a^{k(1-p)}=(a-1)2^{-k}.
$$
The geometric series of general term $2^{-k}$ converges hence the original series converges.

There is a variant of this, where one considers the slabs of integers limited by the powers of $2$. The contribution of slab $k$ is then at most the number of terms $2^k$ times the greatest term $1/2^{kp}$. This reduces the problem to the convergence of the geometric series of general term $b^k$, where $b=2^{1-p}<1$.

Finally, as everybody knows, a simple proof of the convergence of the geometric series of general term $b^k$, for every $b$ in $(0,1)$ say, is to note that the partial sums $s_k$ are such that $s_0=1$ and $s_{k+1}=1+bs_k$, and to show by induction on $k$ that $s_k\le1/(1-b)$ for every $k\ge0$.

**Edit** The so-called variant above shows, using $b=2^{1-p}$, that the sum of the series is at most $1/(1-b)=2^p/(2^p-2)$. But the contribution of slab $k$ is also at least the number of terms $2^k$ times the smallest term $1/2^{(k+1)p}$, hence the sum of the series is at least $1/(2^p-2)$. Finally the sum of the series is between $1/(2^p-2)$ and $2^p/(2^p-2)$.

Comment: are you familiar with Cauchy's Condensation Test?  Because this really looks pretty similar to it.

Comment: @Pete: I am. $ $

Comment: okay, had I seen your quite erudite comments on the subject to Joriki's answer earlier I would not have asked. :)

Comment: @Pete: No problem. In fact your question made me re-think about this whole condensation test thing, which led to the comments on @joriki's answer. So, in the end, I *benefitted* from your question. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Here is another proof:

By Bernoulli

$$\frac{(n+1)^p}{n^p} \geq 1+ \frac{p}{n}=\frac{n+1}{n}+\frac{p-1}{n}$$

Multiplying by $n$ and dividing by $(n+1)^{p}$ you get

$$\frac{1}{n^{p-1}}\geq \frac{1}{(n+1)^{p-1}} + \frac{p-1}{(n+1)^p}$$

or

$$\frac{p-1}{(n+1)^p} \leq \frac{1}{n^{p-1}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{p-1}}  $$

Thus,

$$(p-1) \sum_{n=2}^{m+1} \frac{1}{n^p}=(p-1) \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{(n+1)^p} \leq  \sum_{n=1}^m  \frac{1}{n^{p-1}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{p-1}}\,.$$

Since the last sum is telescopic you get

$$(p-1) \sum_{n=2}^{m+1} \frac{1}{n^p} \leq 1- \frac{1}{(m+1)^{p-1}}$$

Comment: Bernoulli's inequality is wrong for $1\lt p\lt2$. For $p\geqslant2$, simpler methods exist.

Comment: @DidierPiau Thanks, forgot about that :) It's fixed now, I think, anyhow, Bernoulli for real powers uses analysis....

Comment: Yes, basically this is a comparison with the integral of $x\mapsto1/x^p$ on suitable intervals, which explains why the sum is telescopic.

Comment: Actually, this is similar to [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4751976) to another question. Bernoulli on integer exponents can be [proven using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), and further [extended to rational exponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/327189), also using induction.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose what joriki proved could be phrased as $$|\zeta(s)| \leq \frac{1}{1-2^{1-\sigma}} \ \ \ \ \ \forall \sigma >1 , \ \ s=\sigma+it$$ Instead of taking the sum in his second line over $\mathbb{Z}_2,$ one could do this over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ for any integer $q>1$ to get the nice inequality $$\sum_{n > q}\frac{1}{n^\sigma} \leq q^{1-\sigma} \ \ \zeta(\sigma) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \sigma>1, \ q \geq 2, q \in \mathbb{Z}$$ Now given any real $x>2$ we can use $q=1+[x]$ in the case that $x$ is not an integer to get  $$\zeta_{x}(\sigma):=\sum_{n > x}\frac{1}{n^\sigma} \leq x^{1-\sigma} \ \ \zeta(\sigma) +O(\frac{1}{x^{\sigma}})\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \sigma>1, \ x \geq 2, x \in \mathbb{R}$$ and we can therefore phrase this as $$\zeta(s)=\zeta_{x}(s)+O(\frac{x^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}+\frac{1}{x^{\sigma}}) \ \ \ \ \forall \sigma>1, \ x \geq 2, x \in \mathbb{R}$$ uniformly in the stated regions. This inequality might be of some interest regarding the truncated zeta function.

Answer (score 2):

We first show that for $k\geq 1$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)\dotsb(n+k)}=\frac{1}{k\times k!}\tag{0}.
$$
This result combined with the limit comparison test will yield the fact that $\sum n^{-p}<\infty$ for $p>1$.

Indeed, the series in (0) telescopes as can be seen from the partial fraction decomposition
$$
\frac{1}{n(n+1)\dotsb(n+k)}=\frac{1}{k}\left(
\frac{1}{n(n+1)\dotsb(n+k-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)\dotsb(n+k)}
\right)
$$
whence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{n(n+1)\dotsb(n+k)}=\frac{1}{k}\left(
\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(m+1)\dotsb(m+k)}
\right).
$$
Letting $m\to\infty$ yields the result.

Next observe that for $p>1$ we have that
$$
\frac{1}{n^p}\sim\frac{1}{n(n+1)\dotsb(n+p-1)}.
$$
Apply the limit comparison test and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(n)$ = $ \Sigma_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^p}$

then

$S(2n)$ = $S(n)$ + $\frac{1}{{(n+1)}^p} $ +  $\frac{1}{{(n+2)}^p} $ + $\frac{1}{{(n+3)}^p} $ +$\frac{1}{{(n+4)}^p} $ ...........+ $\frac{1}{{(n+n)}^p} $

Let $\Delta S$ = $S(2n) - S(n)$

then 
$\frac{n}{{(2n)}^p}$  $\leq$ $\Delta S$ $\leq$  $\frac{n}{(n+1)^p} $

By sandwitch theorem we see that if $p > 1$,  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \inf}$ $\Delta S = 0$

so that as n tends to infinity  $S(n) = S(2n) = S(4n) ....$

So that series converges

**EDIT:**

$S(2n) - S(n) \leq  \frac{n}{(n+1)^p}  \leq n^{1-p} $

$S(2^{k+1}n) - S(2^{k}n) \leq  \frac{2^{k+1}n - 2^{k}n}{(2^kn+1)^p} \leq \frac{2^{k+1}n - 2^{k}n}{(2^kn)^p} \leq n^{1-p}2^{k(1-p)}$

Summing above equation for k = 0 to m, we get

$S(2^{m+1}n) - S(n) \leq   n^{1-p}(\frac{1-2^{(m+1)(1-p)}}{1-2^{(1-p)}})$

Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} R(n) =\lim_{m \to \infty}S(2^{m+1}n) - S(n) =0 $

Comment: I like the way this post begins, but alas this answer is wrong. In particular, the statement, "as $n$ tends to infinity, $S(n) = S(2n) = S(4n) = \cdots$" does not make sense.

Comment: @Srivatsan, First of all thanks for feedback, as I was eager to know if it is correct. I understand your point so thanks for pointing out that. I will try to improve this proof.

Comment: BTW I did not downvote your post (although I was contemplating it). As I said, I do see a good idea in the post, but the details are all awry.

Comment: @chatur, answer is really similar to answer by N.S

Comment: @Srivatsan, can you please look at the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457418/neighbours-as-function-of-index-for-d2q9-lattice

Answer (score 1):

We have. $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^p$
$p>1$
S = $1+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^p+\cdots \cdot$.
clearly,
$$
\begin{aligned}
S & <1+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^P+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^p+\cdots \\
& =1+\frac{2}{(2)^p}+\frac{4}{(4)^p}+\frac{8}{(8)^p}+...
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
=1+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{p-1}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2(p-1)}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3(p-1)}+\cdots \cdots
$$
which is sum of an infinite geometric progression.
$$
\Rightarrow s<\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{p-1}} \text { if }\left|\frac{1}{2}\right|_{\text {which is true since p>1}}^{p-1}<1
$$
$\Rightarrow S$ is bounded above.
Also $S$ is an increasing sequence $\Rightarrow S$ converges to $\operatorname{sup}(S)$.

Comment: My first answer.pls ignore latex errors.