# Showing $\sum _{k=1} 1/k^2 = \pi^2/6$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2)
>   [Does $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1 / k ^ 2$ converge when $n\rightarrow\infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58931/does-sum-limits-k-1n-1-k-2-converge-when-n-rightarrow-infty)

I read my book of EDP, and there appears the next serie
$$\sum _{k=1} \dfrac{1}{k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$
And, also, we prove that this series is equal $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ for methods od analysis of Fourier, but...

Do you know other proof, any more simple or beautiful?

Comment: That should be $\pi^2/6$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2)

Comment: @Martin: This question asks for methods to calculate the sum, not to prove its convergence. This is at least how I read this question.

Comment: @Asaf I think you' right. Although, the body is different from the title. Which explains why I thought that the OP asks about convergence only. (It's not that important now, since we found *duplicates* for both possible meanings.)

Comment: The title originally said **Prove that this series converges**

Answer (score 15):

Fourteen proofs compiled by Robin Chapman.

http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to show it converges, then the partial sums are increasing but the whole series is bounded above by $$1+\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx=2$$ and below by $$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx=1,$$ since $\int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{x^2} dx \lt \frac{1}{k^2} \lt \int_{k-1}^{k} \frac{1}{x^2} dx$.