# Proving $\frac{1}{n^2}$ infinite series converges without integral test

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just out of curiosity, I was wondering if anybody knows any methods (other than the integral test) of proving the infinite series where the nth term is given by $\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/self-contained-proof-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1np-converges-for

Comment: Cauchy Condensation. Works for $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$, $p\gt 1$.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{n(n-1)}.$$

> $$\frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n(n - 1)} = 1 - \frac12 + \frac12 - \frac13 + \ldots + \frac{1}{n - 1}-\frac1n = 1 - \frac1n \to 1.$$

Comment: I like this solution very much.

Comment: I'm missing something... how do you end up with that expansion?

Comment: He did a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @dfeuer, $\frac{1}{n(n-1)} = \frac{n-(n-1)}{n(n-1)}$.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Nice telescope, Galileo.

Answer (score 16):

With fewer words. Hopefully clear enough. Oresme's style, but converging this time,
and proving that the sum is $<2$.

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to have a source for this? I'd like to see others like this if there is some central repository...

Comment: I've seen it in some calculus book. I reproduced this with Mathematica.

Comment: I guess it would look neater with narrower borders.

Comment: May be, @Pedro. First I had no borders at all, then very thin ones, then way too thick. This is a compromise. I agree with you in the sense that the next stack would look horrible with this border thickness. Too bad I already closed the notebook. Also, there would be more orphaned images at imgur :-/

Comment: This is a very good illustration of the cauchy's condensation test that for a positive non-increasing function $f(n)$ the series $\sum f(n)$ and $\sum 2^{n}f(2^{n})$ converge/diverge together.