# Use Cauchy Criterion to prove the convergence of $x_n=1+\frac{1}{ 2^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Use Cauchy Criterion to prove the convergence of $x_n=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+ \ldots +\frac{1}{n^2}$

> My attempt
>
> Take $|x_m-x_n|$, where $m>n$,
>
> We have $|x_m-x_n|=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{m^2}$

Then I am unable to think up of a bound that tends to zero as $n,m\to\infty$.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \left(\frac1n - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$.

Comment: $|x_m-x_n|=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{m^2}\leq\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+...\frac{1}{(m-1)m}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}$ I still cannot think of a way to continue

Comment: That's less than $\frac1n$. So, generally, $\lvert x_n - x_m\rvert < \dfrac{1}{\min \{m,n\}}$.

Comment: A few related questions (you can surely find more such questions here): [Does $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1 / k ^ 2$ converge when $n\rightarrow\infty$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58931/does-sum-limits-k-1n-1-k-2-converge-when-n-rightarrow-infty),
[Proving $\frac{1}{n^2}$ infinite series converges without integral test](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473762/proving-frac1n2-infinite-series-converges-without-integral-test),
[Need to prove the sequence $a_n=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333417/)

Comment: thanks daniel, sorry martin, i merely searched questions titled cauchy criterion. I will try harder next time