# The sequence $\phi_n= 1+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n^4}$ is bounded above .

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

A sequence $(\phi_n)$ is defined as follows : $$\phi_n= 1+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n^4}$$
Show that the sequence is convergent.

Because this sequence is monotonic, proving it is bounded above will be sufficient to prove that it is convergent.

So how to show that this sequence is bounded above?

Comment: $1/n^4$? Not rather $n/n^4 = 1/n^3$?

Comment: Sorry.. I made the edit.. Its actually 1/n^4

Comment: For this sort of problem, the first thing one should do is compare it with corresponding integral.

Comment: You can have a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58931/does-sum-limits-k-1n-1-k-2-converge-when-n-rightarrow-infty) and also other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/58931). If you have a look, you might be able to use the same method here.

Comment: See [Riemann $\zeta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). $\phi_n$ converges to $\dfrac{\pi^4}{90}.$

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple approach :

$$k^4 \geq k^2 \geq k(k-1)$$ so :

$$\phi_n=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k^4} \leq 1+\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac {1}{k(k-1)}$$ but the later sum telescopes because $$\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$$ so :

$$\phi_n \leq 1+1-\frac{1}{n}=2-\frac{1}{n}<2$$ so this sequence is bounded and then because of monotony it's also convergent .

As an aside the sum actually converges to :$$\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$$

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 1):

Since $t \mapsto \dfrac{1}{t^4}$ is decreasing, we have
$$\frac{1}{(k+1)^4}=\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dt}{(k+1)^4}\leq \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dt}{t^4},\,\,\, k\geq1,$$ which gives$$\phi_n= 1+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n^4}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(k+1)^4}\leq 1+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dt}{t^4}=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3n^3}<\frac{4}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The following approach will also give a reasonable bound:

$$1+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{5^4}+\frac{1}{6^4}+\frac{1}{7^4}+\frac{1}{8^4}+\frac{1}{9^4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n^4} \\ < 1+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{8^4}+\frac{1}{8^4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n^4} \\ < 1+\frac{2}{2^4}+\frac{4}{4^4}+\frac{8}{8^4}+\frac{16}{16^4}+\ldots = 1+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{4^3}+\frac{1}{8^3}+\frac{1}{16^3}+\ldots \\ = 1+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8^2}+\frac{1}{8^3}+\frac{1}{8^4}+\ldots < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{8^k} = \frac87$$

Answer (score -1):

$$ \phi_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^4} \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty $$

Comment: You should explain why $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$$ converges.