# convergence of $\sum_{l=2}^\infty{\frac{1}{l^m}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to check if the series is convergent:

$$\sum_{l=2}^\infty{\frac{1}{l^m}}, m  \ge 3$$

On the one hand I think that it has to be divergent because
each iteration there will be added something more like the harmonic series.

On the other hand I think it has to be convergent because to some extend the sum value will be so small that it does not matter anymore.

Comment: Depends on $m$. What do you know about $m$?

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: Do you know how to compare a series to an integral?

Comment: no, I do not know that

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong because $l^m$ grows faster than $l$.

Comment: What do you know? Have you read the answers at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101131/p-series-convergence ?

Comment: Do you know that the series converges for $m=2?$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29450/9464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting
$$
S_N:=\sum_{l=2}^N{\frac{1}{l^m}}, \quad m  \ge 3
$$ we have
$$
S_{N+1}-S_N=\frac{1}{l^m}>0,
$$
$\{S_N\}$  is an increasing sequence then observing that, for $m\ge3$,
$$
S_N=\sum_{l=2}^N{\frac{1}{l^m}}<\sum_{l=2}^N{\frac{1}{l(l+1)}}=\frac12-\frac1{N+1}<\frac12
$$ $\{S_N\}$  is then a bounded sequence, the given series is thus convergent.

Comment: can the same be applicable if $m>1$ ? your ans is beautiful

Comment: don't you think it is $\frac{1}{l(l-1)}$ instead of $\frac{1}{l(l+1)}$?

Comment: @Anjan3 Thank you. Since $m\ge3$ and $l\geq2$, then it's OK that $\frac{1}{l^m}<\frac{1}{l(l+1)},$ as one may check. A proof for $m>1$ probably needs to compare $\frac{1}{l^m}$ with $\frac{1}{l(l-1)}$ as you suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the grouping

$$\frac1{2^m}+\frac1{3^m}+\\
\frac1{4^m}+\frac1{5^m}+\frac1{6^m}+\frac1{7^m}+\\
\frac1{8^m}+\frac1{9^m}+\frac1{10^m}+\frac1{11^m}+\frac1{12^m}+\frac1{13^m}+\frac1{14^m}+\frac1{15^m}+\\\cdots
$$
with doublings of the number of terms.

As every term in a group is bounded above by its first element $1/2^{km}$, and as there are $2^k$ terms per group, a group contributes less than $2^{(1-m)k}$, forming a geometric series of common ratio $2^{1-m}$.

$$S<\frac2{2^m}+\frac4{4^m}+\frac8{8^m}+\cdots$$

You can conclude about convergence.

Comment: What do the variables k and s mean ?

Comment: @jublikon: this is obvious, spend some effort.