# for what values of x the series converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For what values of $x$ the series summation$x^{log(n)}$ converges.

I've just used the necessary condition for the convergence of series that $x^{log(n)}$ should tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity.This is possible only if $|x|<1$.

But this does not surely conclude that the original series converges if $|x|<1$

Answer (score 1):

For $x > 0$:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{\log n}
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{\log x\log n} \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{\log x} \\
&=& \zeta(-\log x)
\end{array}$$

The last equality holds if and only if the series is convergent, which per [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101131/328173) is if and only if $-\log x > 1$, i.e. $x < \dfrac1e$.

Notice that for the series to be defined, we must have $x \ge 0$.

---

The series converges if and only if $x \in \left[0,\dfrac1e\right)$.

Comment: Note that this is not a power series, so "radius of convergence" isn't quite the right term.

Comment: @zhw. what should I write?

Comment: It's fine now, although your first line should just disappear as it's not helping in any way.

Comment: @zhw. expunged.