# Limit Comparison Test on $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n+1}$

I compared it with:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^5}$

The limit is $\frac{2n^5-n^3}{3n^5+2n+1}$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

The limit works out to $\frac23$. I don't understand how this shows convergence? It is less than 1, so why is the p-series, the second series I have, converging?

Comment: What limit works out to $2/3$? I can't think of a limit here that would, offhand.

Comment: Edited to show the limit

Comment: Where does that limit come from? It seems you just took the terms of the sum you want to look at, and randomly chose to multiply them by $n^3$. I don't see the point in doing so.

Comment: Okay, I see why the multiplication by $n^3$ comes in. Why do you think that the limit being $<1$ is relevant? And why do you think that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-3}$ should diverge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed up comparison test and limit comparison test.

Limit comparison test:

Consider two series of non negative reals $\sum  u_n$ and $\sum v_n$ if

$lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{u_n}{v_n}=l \space (0<l< \infty)$ then both the series converge or diverge simultaneously.

---

$u_n=\frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n+1}$

Let $v_n=\frac{1}{n^3}$

Then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n+1}}{\frac{1}{n^3}}=\frac{2}{3}$

Since $\sum \frac{1}{n^3}$ converge ( $\sum\frac{1}{n^p}$ converges for $p>1$ ) , by limit comparison test $\sum\frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n+1}$ also converge.

Note: [Convergence of $p$- series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101131/977780)

Answer (score -1):

The limit is correct. However, since the p-series will diverge if p=1,(since a p-series diverges if 0<p<=1), then the finite, positive limit shows the p-series will diverge. If the p-series diverges, then by the Limit Comparison Test, the other series must diverge as well.

Comment: https://www.calcchat.com/book/Calculus-9e/9/4/19/ The worked out solution is out here, and it seems to follow this logic.

Comment: I see. I had mixed up "comparison" and "limit comparison" in my head, I think I'm seeing where OP is going now.