# How to show the sum of $\frac1{n^r}$ exists for all $r > 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self-Contained Proof that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^p}$ Converges for $p &gt; 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/self-contained-proof-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1np-converges-for)

How would I go about showing that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^{r}}$$

exists for all $r>1$?

Comment: Do you know about the integral test? If so, you can use that one.

Comment: [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/self-contained-proof-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1np-converges-for/29466#29466) a nice proof.

Comment: I'm not sure this should be closed as a duplicate (at least not for the proposed "duplicate"), as this question would allow the integral test to be used, and illustrated, in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use the Integral Test.

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^r}$ and $r > 1$. Note that $f$ is continuous, positive, and decreasing on the interval $[1, \infty)$. Note also that for an integer $n$, you have $f(n) = \frac{1}{n^r}$. So the Integral Test applies. Hence you need to prove that the integral
$$\int_1^{\infty} f(x) dx
$$
is convergent.
You have
$$\begin{align}\int_1^{\infty}f(x) dx &= \lim_{N\to \infty}\int_1^{N} x^{-r} dx\\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} \left[\frac{1}{1-r}x^{1-r}\right]_1^N \\
&= \lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{1-r}\left[\frac{1}{N^{r-1}} - 1\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{r-1}.
\end{align}
$$
We used here that $r > 1$ so $ r-1 > 0$, and so 
$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N^{r-1}} = 0.
$$
So the integral is convergent, so by the Integral Test, the series is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

For $r>1$ the function $\frac{1}{x^r}$ is positive and decreases in the interval
 $[1, \infty)$
then the series converges since the improper integral from 1 to infinite converges. (You can verify the integral convergence because you can find a primitive of the function).