# My proof that a harmonic series diverges..

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = S$ where $S$ is finite.  Then

$$S =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n} > \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n} = S$$

which is a contradiction.  Is this valid?

Comment: It is great...if you can prove that changing the order of summation doesn't alter the sum (which *is true* if you assume the harmonic series converges by absolute convergence, but perhaps you can't use this here) . BTW, your acceptation rate is going to begin diverging...

Comment: You rearrange infinitely many terms and you need to prove that this is valid in the sense that it preserves the value of the sum. (This crucially depends on the fact that all of the terms involved are positive; if they aren't, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem ).

Comment: Reminds me of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/self-contained-proof-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1np-converges-for/29466#29466

Comment: The inequality should be reversed.

Comment: I reversed the direction.

Comment: Rearrangement of a series is OK for nonnegative series, even if they diverge.

Comment: I think I saw this one in the _Monthly_ in the late '90s.  I suspect it was also published a number of times before that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to express your argument more formally is by considering the partial sums

$$S_{2m}=\sum_{n=1}^{2m}\frac1n=\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\frac1{2n-1}+\frac1{2n}\right)\;.$$

You can bound these partial sums as you did to obtain

$$
S_{2m}\gt\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1n=S_m\;.$$

If the series were to converge, the sequences $S_{2m}$ and $S_m$ would have to converge to a common limit, so their difference would have to converge to $0$ for $m\to\infty$, whereas in fact the gap between them increases with $m$.