# PROVE if $x \ge-1 $then $ (1+x)^n \ge 1+nx $ , Every $n \ge 1$

Tags: induction

Use mathematical induction to prove this. Here is my answer but I stuck at certain point.

Base Case:
          n=1  $$(1+x)^1 \ge 1+x $$ True ,

Induction Case:
          n=k
assume    $$(1+x)^k \ge 1+kx $$
          n=k+1
          $$ (1+x)^k+1 \ge 1+(k+1)x $$
          $$(1+x)^k *(1+x) \ge 1+ kx+ x $$

```
      Stuck!!!
```

Comment: Please, fix your post. You didn't write what you want to prove. Also, you can use math-mode to write mathematics in your post, like $(1+x)^k$.

Comment: how to access math mode, how can I write, I am new

Comment: Here: http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex . You use the dollar signs.

Comment: thank for showing me how to edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Bernoulli Inequality, whose proof (by induction) can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Proof_of_the_inequality).

Answer (score 2):

[Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) is proven for integer exponents in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245) by induction and then expanded to rational exponents in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/327189).

Comment: Does it extend to irrationals?

Comment: @Arkamis: By continuity from the rational case, it does.