# Bounds of $f(x)=(1-ax)^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $a\in(0,1)$ be a fixed number. What is the numeric value of upper and lower bound of $f(x)=(1-ax)^{1/x}$ on $x\in (0,1)$?

I feel as though I'm missing something, because it shouldn't be difficult. But trying to find $x$ for which  $f'(x)=0$ is a bad idea to put it mildly and there has to be other way to see, whether $f$ has an extremum or not.

So far all I know is that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1-ax)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\frac{\log{(1-ax)}}{x}}=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log{(1-ax)}}{x}}\stackrel{H}{=}e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-a}{1-ax}}=e^{-a}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 1}(1-ax)^{1/x}=1-a$$

What do you propose to do now? (I hope the first limit is correct)

Answer (score 2):

To find the derivative of $f$, use logarithmic differentiation:
$$
\ln(f(x)) = \ln[(1-ax)^{1/x}] = \frac{\ln(1-ax)}{x}\\
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{-ax/(1-ax) - \ln(1-ax)}{x^2}
= \frac{-ax - (1-ax)\ln(1 - ax)}{x^2(1-ax)}
$$
If we can show that $f'$ never changes sign, we can guarantee that $f$ will be between its limits at $0$ and $1$.
Noting that $f(x)$ is positive on $(0,1)$, it suffices to show that the numerator of the above is never zero, so that $f'/f$ never changes sign.

It may help to rewrite the numerator in the form
$$
(1-ax)[1-\ln(1-ax)]-1
$$

Comment: That's what I meant when I said it wasn't a good idea to concentrate on the derivative, but if that's the only way, then well... Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be missing an application of the chain rule in your differentiation of the logarithm. The numerator should be $-ax - (1-ax)\ln(1-ax)$.

Comment: @RogerBurt good catch!  Thank you for that.

Comment: Ok, but I still can't quite grasp why it doesn't change the sign. All I can say is that $1-\log{(1-ax)}>1$ (right?)

Answer (score 1):

[Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/327189), says that for $ax\le1$ and $\frac yx\ge1$,
$$
1-\frac yxax\le(1-ax)^{y/x}
$$
Therefore, for $ax,ay\le1$ and $0\lt x\le y\le1$,
$$
(1-ay)^{1/y}\le(1-ax)^{1/x}
$$
This means that $f(x)=(1-ax)^{1/x}$ is a decreasing function of $x$. Therefore, for $x\in(0,1]$,
$$
1-a\le(1-ax)^{1/x}\le e^{-a}
$$