# Binomial theorem and the inequality $(1-e^{-x})^{\alpha}\leq (1-\alpha e^{-x})$ for $0<\alpha\le 1$

Tags: inequality, binomial-theorem

Assume $0<\alpha\leq 1$ and $x>0$. Does the following inequality hold?
$$(1-e^{-x})^{\alpha}\leq (1-\alpha e^{-x})$$
I know that the reverse inequality holds if $\alpha\ge 1$.

Comment: In fact, I believe the reverse inequality holds

Comment: Reverse inequality hold if $\alpha >1$.

Comment: Ah, thanks sudha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Bernoulli's Inequality**

The reverse inequality, for $a\ge1$, is called [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality). It can be proven, in the case of integer exponents, [using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245). This can be extended to the case of rational exponents, again [using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/327189).

The inequality you mention above, for $0\lt a\le1$, follows immediately.

---

**Using the AM-GM Inequality**

For $x\gt0$ and $0\le a\le1$, the [AM-GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality) says that
$$
1^{1-a}x^a\le(1-a)1+ax
$$
Substituting $x\mapsto1-x$ yields that for $x\lt1$ and $0\le a\le1$
$$
(1-x)^a\le1-ax
$$

Answer (score 2):

For $x > 0$, $0 < e^{-x} < 1$ (and this is a bijection between $(0,\infty)$ and $(0,1)$), so you can drop the exponentials and ask the same question about $$(1-y)^\alpha \leq 1-\alpha y$$
for $\alpha \in (0,1]$ and $y\in(0,1)$. Then, this should just be an exercise of convexity: consider the function $y\in(0,1) \mapsto (1-y)^\alpha$, for $\alpha \in (0,1]$.

Comment: You just re-iterated my question.

Comment: No. Have you even read my answer? The word "convexity" should be a hint. If a function is concave, then it is _____ its asymptotes. And you should know how to prove a smooth and easily differentiable function is convex or concave. If you are looking for a full-fledged, complete and detailed answer without your actually having to do anything, then indeed this is not what I gave.

Comment: @sudhapandey And also the annoying $e^{-x}$ has been washed away.