# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n}n!}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I managed to prove the sequence is monotonic and bounded which means it is convergent. Though, I couldn't evaluate the limit itself. I tried to use a comparation test with no results. Anyway, the result is 0. Any help will bi appreciated.

Comment: There is a typo in the title of the question, please fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit of $2^{n} n!/n^{n}$ as $n \to \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570916/limit-of-2n-n-nn-as-n-to-infty)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

By ratio test

$$\frac{\frac{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{2^{n}(n)!}{n^{n}}}=2\left(\frac n {n+1}\right)^n=\frac2{\left(1+\frac 1 {n}\right)^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: use *equivalence* and *Stirling's formula*:
$$n!\sim_{\infty}\sqrt{2\pi n}\Bigl(\frac n{\mathrm e}\Bigr)^n,$$so
$$\frac{2^{n}n!}{n^n}\sim_{\infty}\sqrt{2\pi n}\Bigl(\frac 2{\mathrm e}\Bigr)^n$$
Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Bernard, thank you for the hint. I think the next step is to convert the form: $0\infty$ to indeterminate expression: $\frac{0}{0}$ and then to apply l'Hospital's rule,right?

Comment: Not necessary: it only uses a highschool result (if $\alpha>0$ and $\,0<a<1,\:x^\alpha  a^x\to 0$).