# How to show that: if $n\ln\left(1+a/n\right)\geqslant k\ln\left(1+a/k\right)$ then $n\geqslant k$?

Tags: inequality

Let $a>0$ and $n,k$ positive integers.

If 
$$n\ln\left(1+a/n\right)\geqslant k\ln\left(1+a/k\right),$$
then
$$n\geqslant k.$$

I tried by contrapositive by I do not get much. If $n<k$ then I would have 
$$\ln\left(1+a/n\right)>\ln\left(1+a/k\right),$$
which does not help me a lot.

Comment: Have you tried bringing the leading terms in as a power and then showing $(1+a/n)^n \geq (1+a/k)^k$?

Comment: Yes I transform it to that inequality but then blocked.

Comment: It might be easier to go the other direction, assume $n \geq k$ and iff your way to the initial assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if $n\gt m\gt0$ and $a\gt0$, then [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) says
$$
\left(1+\frac an\right)^{n/m}\gt\left(1+\frac an\frac nm\right)=\left(1+\frac am\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left(1+\frac an\right)^n\gt\left(1+\frac am\right)^m
$$
Reversing roles we have that for $m\gt n\gt0$,
$$
\left(1+\frac an\right)^n\lt\left(1+\frac am\right)^m
$$
Taking logarithms proves the required implication.

Comment: Good old Bernoulli's inequality - the swiss army knife of inequalities.

Comment: @martycohen: indeed! It is quite useful in cases like this.

Comment: Though the version of BI proved by induction is for integer exponents. I'm not sure if the version you use can be proven as simply. I have supplied an answer here that uses calculus and works for any n and k, not just integers.

Comment: @martycohen: please take a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/327189). It extends the integer version to rational exponents via induction. That is all we need here. Real exponents require continuity, but that follows from the definition of $a^x$ for real $x$.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: very nice. upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$f(x)
=x \ln(1+a/x)
$.

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=\ln(1+a/x)+x(\ln(1+a/x))'\\
&=\ln(1+a/x)+x\frac{(1+a/x)'}{1+a/x}\\
&=\ln((x+a)/x)+x\frac{-a/x^2}{1+a/x}\\
&=-\ln(x/(x+a))-\frac{a}{x+a}\\
&=-\ln(1-a/(x+a))-\frac{a}{x+a}\\
&\gt a/(x+a)-\frac{a}{x+a}
\qquad\text{since }-\ln(1-z) > z \text{ for }z > 0\\
&= 0\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$f(x)$
is increasing,
which is what you want.