# Inequality with floor function

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I need some help to prove this inequality:

$\ (1 + \frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n} \le (1 + \frac{1}{\lfloor{a_n}\rfloor})^{\lfloor{a_n}\rfloor + 1} $

where $\ n \in \mathbb{N} $ and$\ a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ with$\ a_n > 1 $ is any element of a sequence.

Comment: I don't get it. There is no further conditions on $a_n$? I mean, e.g. with $a_3=8$ it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't get why you need the floor function if $n$ is a natural number.

Comment: If $\lfloor n\rfloor =n$, why even include it in the inequality?

Comment: sorry, I miss a_, in the second part of inequality

Comment: Doesn't  $LHS < e < RHS$ hold generally (at least for *positive* $a_n$) ?

Comment: I believe you'll also need $a_n > 1$ for this to hold.

Comment: Yes, this is a part of an exercise to prove that sequence converges to e.
The exercise ask to apply Squeeze theorem, to prove that sequence converges  to e.
I already proven the other part of inequality, but I am unable to prove this part...

Comment: In the exercise there are no other constraints for $\ a_n $, but since this proof, is used for another proof with $\ a_n $ which tends to $\ +\infty $, we can require $\ a_n > 1 $ to make valid the inequality.

Comment: You cant prove that the sequence converges to $e$ generally because the limit of this sequence is **the definition** of $e$. At most you want to prove that the sequence converge for some value between $2$ and $3$ what we call $e$.

Comment: In my book the the definition of e is the limit of $\(1+\frac{1}{n})^n $.  
The exercise ask to prove that also $\(1+\frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n} $ converges to e.
The exercise ask to use this inequality: $\ (1 + \frac{1}{a_n + 1})^{\lfloor a_n \rfloor } \le  (1 + \frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n} \le (1 + \frac{1}{\lfloor{a_n}\rfloor})^{\lfloor{a_n}\rfloor + 1} $ to give a proof.

Comment: Sorry the correct inequality is $\ (1 + \frac{1}{\lfloor{a_n}\rfloor + 1})^{\lfloor a_n \rfloor } \le  (1 + \frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n} \le (1 + \frac{1}{\lfloor{a_n}\rfloor})^{\lfloor{a_n}\rfloor + 1} $

I already proven with definition that both extremes of inequality converges to e.
I was also able to prove that the first part of inequality is valid for any $\ a_n > 1 $, but I am unable to prove the second part of inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**An Elementary Answer**

Since $\lfloor x\rfloor+1\ge x$, we can use [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality):
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right)^{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}
&=\left[\left(1+\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right)^{\large\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}x}\right]^{\normalsize\,x}\\
&\ge\left(1+\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}{\lfloor x\rfloor x}\right)^{\normalsize x}\\[9pt]
&\ge\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x
\end{align}
$$
for $x\ge1$, so that $\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ exists.

---

**Notes on Bernoulli's Inequality**

At the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245/13854), Bernoulli's Inequality is proven for integer exponents using only induction.

At the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/327189/13854), the integer version is extended to the rational version using only induction.

Comment: Thanks, for sure this is a good solution, but the exercise ask to use the inequality with floor function.
Furthermore the exercise in my book is before the chapter of derivative, so I think this is not the expected solution.
So I give you an upvote, but I can't accept as an answer.

Comment: For $a_n\ge1$, set $x=a_n$ and $y=\lfloor a_n\rfloor$, and you get the inequality you ask about

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but I prefer to wait some time to see if someone can provide a solution without the use of derivatives.
Otherwise I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose the exercise requires the use of  Bernoulli's Inequality.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti: If you want an answer not using derivatives, it would be nice to specify that in the question. I have added an answer using only Bernoulli's Inequality.