# Show that $ \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ is uniformly convergent on $S=[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Show that $ \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ is uniformly convergent on $S=[0,1]$.

Given $f_n(x)=\left( 1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ is a sequence of bounded function on $[0,1]$ and $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a bounded function , then $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly  to $f$ iff

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||f_n - f|| = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\sup |f_n(x) - f(x)| \right)= 0$$

As $$f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$$

We have

$$\begin{split}
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left\|\left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n - e^x\right\| &= \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|\sup_{x \in S}\left[\left( 1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n - e^x \right ]\right|\\
&= \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n - e^1 \right|\\
&= \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} |e-e| \\
&= 0
\end{split}
$$

I am new to sequence. Is this appropriate to show convergence?

Going back to the definition, How can I show that:

1. "$f_n(x)=\left( 1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ is a sequence of bounded function on $[0,1]$"?
2. $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a bounded function?

Comment: Continuous functions are bounded on closed intervals. For any $n$, $f_n(x)$ expands to a polynomial, which is continuous anywhere.

Comment: The third line in your last calculation is wrong: shouldn't have a limit in front of $|e-e|$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic how does it make a difference?

Comment: @Will Fisher: no, the point of the problem is to *prove* $f_n\to f$ uniformly. IntegrateThis gave the right answer to question 1. The right answer to question 2 is similar: we know what $f$ is, and we know it's continuous, and a continuous function on a closed interval is bounded.

Comment: @Will Fisher: well, sure, as written it doesn't make a difference. But the point is that it in preserving the limit from the second to the third line it looks like the student is arguing that $|(1+1/n)^n-e|$ *equals* $|e-e|$.

Comment: @Will Fisher: **no**, you have misunderstood the OP. The OP is proving that $f_n\to f$ uniformly by invoking hypotheses, and the questions at the bottom are about how to show the hypotheses hold.

Comment: @symplectomorphic You are correct, I misread. However the OP does not need to show they are bounded to invoke this criterion for uniform convergence.

Comment: @Will Fisher: your last comment is right and could be explained in an answer.

Comment: Have you shown that the sup obtains when $x=1$? It is true, but it seems to me to require proof (and you have the absolute value in the wrong place:  as it stands - the absolute value of the sup of the difference-, the sup is 0 at $x=0$; you want the sup of the absolute value of the difference instead).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to verify the precise maximum you can bound as

$$0 \leqslant e^x - \left(1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n =e^x \left[1 -  \left(1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^ne^{-x}\right] \\ \leqslant  e^x \left[1 -  \left(1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n \left(1 - \frac{x}{n} \right)^n\right] \\ =  e^x \left[1 -  \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2} \right)^n \right],$$

since $e^{x/n} > 1 + x/n$ which implies $e^{x} > (1 + x/n)^n $ for $x \in (-n,\infty).$

By Bernoulli's inequality, $(1 - x^2/n^2)^n \geqslant 1 - x^2/n$ and

$$0 \leqslant e^x - \left(1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n \leqslant \frac{e^xx^2}{n} \leqslant \frac{e}{n},$$

which enables you to prove uniform convergence on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write explicitly  the difference 
$$e^x - ( 1 + \frac{x}{n})^n = \sum_{ k \ge 0} \frac{x^k}{k!} - \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right )^k=\\
=\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{[1-\prod_{l=1}^{k-1}(1- l/n)] x^k}{k!}$$.  Since every coefficient $1- \prod_{l=1}^{k-1} (1-\frac{l}{n})$ is $\ge 0$ ( and $0$ for $k \ge n+1$ ) we conclude that

$$0 < e^x - (1+ \frac{x}{n})^n\le e^1 - (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$$ for all $n \ge 0$ and $x\in [0,1]$.

Now, it's only necessary to check ( or use ) that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \to e$.

Comment: Alternative approach : notice that the sequence of functions $(1+ \frac{x}{n})^n$ is increasing and use Dini't theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

As shown in inequality $(2)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/327189), $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ is increasing in $n$. Thus, for $x\ge0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(e^x-\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\right)
&=e^x-\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n-1}\\
&\ge e^x-\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\\[3pt]
&\ge0
\end{align}
$$
So on $[0,1]$,
$$
0\le e^x-\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\le e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm $\ln:[1,e]\to[0,1]$ is uniformly continuous on this interval, so it is a 
uniform homeomorphism, and it suffices to show that $\ln f_n(x)=n\ln (1+x/n)$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.  But this follows immediately from Taylor's theorem:
$$
n\ln(1+x/n)-x=O(x^2/n).
$$