# Computing the limit $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^k x^n \left(1 - \frac{x}{k} \right)^k \mathrm{d} x$ for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I'm working on a problem that asks to compute
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^k x^n \left(1 - \frac{x}{k} \right)^k \mathrm{d} x$$
for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$. What I've tried so far is to do a $u$-substitution for $u = \frac{x}{k}$, so I have
$$\int_0^k x^n \left(1 - \frac{x}{k} \right)^k \mathrm{d} x = k^{n + 1} \int_0^1 u^n (1 - u)^k \mathrm{d} u .$$
Using the Binomial Theorem to break up the $(1 - u)^k$ term, I get
$$k^{n + 1} \int_0^1 u^n (1 - u)^k \mathrm{d} u = k^{n + 1} \int_0^1 \sum_{j = 0}^k \binom{k}{j} \frac{(-1)^j}{n + j + 1} .$$
However, I don't know how to compute the limit of this expression as $k \to \infty$. I assume that I should recognize it as some kind of Taylor series that's somehow $O \left( k^{-(n + 1)} \right)$, but I'm not seeing it.

> **Note:** When looking at other posts, I found an integral that looked similar to this one, and the only answer on that post involved something called a beta function. I have never heard of a beta function, and would like to find a solution here that doesn't rely on whatever a beta function is.

Another idea I considered was to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem, since $e^{-x} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{x}{k} \right)^k$, so I figured I could use DCT to say that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^k x^n \left( 1 - \frac{x}{k} \right)^k \mathrm{d} x & = \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \chi_{[0, k]}(x) x^n \left( 1 - \frac{x}{k} \right)^k \mathrm{d} x \\
& = \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x} \mathrm{d} x & (\textrm{DCT used here})\\
& = n ! ,
\end{align*}
assuming I didn't mess up any of my integration by parts. However, I couldn't find a choice of dominator that would work on all of $[0, \infty)$, so I'd also be interested in a solution that uses DCT as well. Perhaps I'm being naive, but the pointwise limit is just so convenient that I have to imagine that DCT can be used here.

EDIT: Thanks to some inspiration from a comment by user Mars Plastic, I thought to consider some other integral convergence theorems. I came up with this, which I think works. I'm still interested to see if the Dominated Convergence Theorem argument can be made to work, perhaps a bit more smoothly than this.

Let $f_k(x) = \chi_{[0, k]}(x) x^n \left( 1 - \frac{x}{k} \right)^k$. I claim that the sequence is monotone increasing on $[0, \infty)$. Fix $x \in (0, \infty)$, and let $K = \lfloor k \rfloor + 1$, so that $K = \min \{ k \in \mathbb{N} : f_k(x) \neq 0 \}$. Obviously if $k < K$, then $f_k(x) = 0 \leq f_{k + 1}(x)$. So consider the case where $k \geq K$. Then $f_k(x) = x^n \left(1 - \frac{x}{k} \right)^k$, and based on answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2697929/192914), it seems this sequence would be monotone increasing. Therefore, I can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem to say that $f_k(x) \nearrow x^n e^{-x}$, so $$\int_0^k x^n \left( 1 - \frac{x}{k} \right)^k \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^\infty f_k(x) \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x} = n! .$$

Comment: I'm not an analysis kind of guy and I can't help, but +1 for showing some real thoughts and work.

Comment: @Randall Thanks. I know that nobody likes posts that just toss up a homework problem and wait for someone to come solve it, so I try to make sure that whatever I post shows as much of my thought process as there is to show.

Comment: Just a minor observation: By using Fatou's Lemma instead of the (unjustified) Dominated Convergence Theorem, you can get at least that $n!$ is a lower bound for the expression you'd like to compute.

Comment: DCT works with the dominating function $x^ne^{-x}$. To show that this indeed dominates the integrands, you may consider using the inequality $1-x\leq e^{-x}$. Even better, MCT also works in this case. (To show that the integrand is increasing in $n$, you may use the [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).)

Comment: As for your first approach, you may also consider using the beta function identity $$\int_{0}^{1}x^a(1-x)^b\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a!b!}{(a+b+1)!}.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Are you pulling my leg?

Comment: **Lemma.** Let $x\in\mathbb R^+$ and $n\in\mathbb N$. Then $\lvert \chi_{[0, k]}(x) x^n \left( 1 - \frac{x}{k} \right)^k\rvert\le x^ne^{-x}$. 

*Proof.* With the given conditions it follows that $\lvert \chi_{[0, k]}(x) x^n\rvert\le x^n$. Observe that $\lvert\left( 1 - \frac{x}{k} \right)^k\rvert=\rvert1 - \frac{x}{k}\rvert^k$ and let $y=-\frac{x}{k}$ to rewrite $\lvert 1+y\rvert\le e^y$.
This inequality is a slight variation of [Bernoulli's_inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) and holds for all $y\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: For the last step we have to prove that $x^ne^{-x}$ is integrable on $x\in\mathbb R^+$, which can be done using integration by parts to show that this integral is equal to $n!<\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

To apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, it suffices to show that $\left( 1 - \frac{x}{k}  \right)^k \leq e^{-x}$ on $(0,k)$, because, if so, we have the uniform bound $$x^n \left( 1 - \frac{x}{k}  \right)^k \chi_{(0,k)} \leq x^ne^{-x} $$
on $(0, \infty)$, for all $n$. Since $x^ne^{-x}$ is integrable, the conditions of LDCT would be met.

Now, observe our claim is equivalent to showing that $f(x) = k \log \left( 1 - \frac{x}{k} \right) + x \leq 0$ for $ x\in (0,k)$. Note that the inequality holds for $f(0) = 0$. Also, $$f^\prime (x) = 1-\frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{k}}  = -\frac{x/k}{1-x/k} < 0 \qquad x \in (0,k)$$
Thus, $f$ is decreasing on $(0,k)$, and $f(x) \leq 0$ on $x \in (0,k)$, as desired.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\displaystyle I(n, k) =  \int_0^1 u^n (1 - u)^k \,\mathrm{d} u$. Then integrating by parts:

$\begin{aligned}  I(n, k) & =  \frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1 (u^{n+1})' (1 - u)^k \,\mathrm{d} u \\& = \frac{1}{n+1}\cdot u^{n+1}(1-u)^{k}\bigg|_0^1-\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1 u^{n+1}[(1-u)^{k}]'\, \mathrm du \\& = \frac{k}{n+1}\int_0^1 u^{n+1}(1-u)^{k-1}\, \mathrm du  \\& = \frac{k}{n+1} I(n+1, k-1).  \end{aligned}$

Carrying out the recurrences:

$\begin{aligned}  I(n, k) & = \frac{k}{n+1} I(n+1, k-1) \\& = \frac{k}{n+1}\cdot \frac{k-1}{n+2} \cdots \frac{1}{n+k}I(n+k, 0) \\& = \frac{k}{n+1}\cdot \frac{k-1}{n+2} \cdots \frac{1}{n+k}\int_0^{1} u^{n+k} \, \mathrm du 
 \\& = \frac{k}{n+1}\cdot \frac{k-1}{n+2} \cdots \frac{1}{n+k} \cdot \frac{1}{n+k+1} \\& = \frac{k!n!}{(k+n+1)!}. \end{aligned}  $

Therefore

$$I = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k!n! k^{n+1}}{(k+n+1)!} = n! \cdot \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k! k^{n+1}}{(k+n+1)!} = n!$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick rundown on a Beta function, as it is useful in this case but also good to know in general:
$$\begin{align}
\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)=&\int_0^\infty u^{x-1}e^{-u}\,du\int_0^\infty v^{y-1}e^{-v}\,dv\\
=&\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty u^{x-1}v^{y-1}e^{-(u+v)}\,du\,dv
\end{align}$$
then using $u=zt,v=z(1-t)$ gives:
$$\begin{align}
\phantom{a}&\int_0^\infty\int_0^1e^{-z}(zt)^{x-1}(z(1-t))^{y-1}z\,dt\,dz\\
\phantom{a}&\underbrace{\int_0^\infty e^{-z}z^{(x+y)-1}\,dz}_{\Gamma(x+y)}\cdot\underbrace{\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt}_{B(x,y)}
\end{align}$$
and so it follows that:
$$B(x,y)=\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$
where $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$

---

In your case:
$$k^{n+1}\int_0^1u^n(1-u)^k\,du=k^{n+1}B(n+1,k+1)=k^{n+1}\frac{n!k!}{(n+k+1)!}$$

Comment: Interesting though this may be in its own right, part of my reason for not wanting to focus on it in this situation is that this problem is from a past exam, so I didn’t want to rely on it for thinking about this problem.