# How to show that $uv \le \frac {u^p}{p}+ \frac {v^q}{q}$ where $\frac 1p + \frac 1q = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, inequality

> Let $u, v, p, q > 0$, and let $\dfrac 1p + \dfrac 1q = 1$. Then
>
> $$uv \le \dfrac {u^p}{p}+ \dfrac {v^q}{q}$$
>
> Show that equality occurs iff $u^p = v^q$.

This is problem $10$ from Ch. 6 in Rudin's PMA (integration chapter). I tried two approaches:

**Approach 1:**

Solving $\frac 1p + \frac 1q = 1$ for $q$ gives  $q = \dfrac {p}{p-1}$. Letting $p=x$ we make the RHS of the inequality into a function: $f(x) = \dfrac {u^x}{x}+\dfrac {v^{\frac {x}{x-1}}}{\frac {x}{x-1}}= \dfrac {u^x}{x}+\dfrac {x-1}{x}v^{\frac {x}{x-1}}$. I plotted $f$ and the results look promising for a first derivative test:

[image]

$f'(x) = \dfrac {u^x x \ln u - u^x}{x^2} + \dfrac {1}{x^2}v^{\frac{x}{x-1}} + \dfrac {1}{x^2} + \dfrac {x}{x-1} \cdot \dfrac {1}{x^2} (\ln v) v^{\frac {x}{x-1}}$.

However, I haven't been able to find the solution to $f'(x) = 0$. Yet I know there must be an analytic solution, because the problem tells us that equality occurs iff $u^p = v^q$, so $u^x = v^ {\frac {x}{x-1}}$, and we can solve this equation for $x$ analytically.

**Approach 2:**

I rewrote the RHS as $\displaystyle \int_0^p u^{t-1} dt + \int_0^q v^{t-1} dt$, but I don't really know what to do from here.

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259826/purely-algebraic-proof-of-youngs-inequality

Comment: This is Young's inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products

Comment: For each $u, p, q$ fixed, define $f(v) = \frac{u^p}p + \frac{v^q}{q} -uv$. $f'(v) = v^{q-1} -u$ has unique solution $v = u^{\frac{1}{q-1}}$, $f'(v) < 0$ if $v <  u^{\frac{1}{q-1}}$ and $f'(v) >0$ if $v >  u^{\frac{1}{q-1}}$. Hence $f(v) \geq f( u^{\frac{1}{q-1}}) =0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way is to prove that $$t \le \frac {t^p}{p} + \frac 1q$$ whenever $t \ge 0$.  Define $$\phi(t) = \frac {t^p}{p} + \frac 1q - t.$$ Then $\phi'(t) = t^{p-1} - 1$, so by the first derivative test $\phi$ attains its minimum at $t=1$.  Thus $\phi(t) \ge \phi(1)$ for all $t \ge 0$ which rearranges to the stated inequality.

Now evaluate the inequality at $t = uv^{1-q}$, then multiply both sides by $v^q$.