# $u_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^\beta}$ converge

Tags: limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self-Contained Proof that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^p}$ Converges for $p &amp;gt; 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/self-contained-proof-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1np-converges-for)

We know that $\lim u_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} =\infty $. But I can't prove that with $\beta >1$:
 $u_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^\beta}$ converge

Comment: Do you know the [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/self-contained-proof-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1np-converges-for/29466#29466) is a beautiful argument by joriki.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $U = u_{\infty}$. Think about the relationship between $iU$ and $U$.

Comment: What is *for you exactly* $\,u_\infty\,$??