# For what values of $p$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{\sin(n)}{n}|^p$ is convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

Let $p>1$ , $p\in\mathbb{R}$. For what values of $p$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{\sin(n)}{n}|^p$ is convergent?

---

When $p=1$, I know the series is divergent but how about other cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p > 1$ we can write:

$0 < \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{\sin(n)}{n}|^p \le \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{n}|^p$

and the right part converges.So the middle part also converges as $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}|\frac{\sin(n)}{n}|^p$ is an increasing function of $k$ and it's limited by $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{n}|^p$.

So for every $p > 1$ it converges.

Comment: That should be $p>1$, not $p \geq 1$

Comment: How do we know $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$ is convergent when p>1$

Comment: @ErginSuer: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/self-contained-proof-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1np-converges-for

Comment: I suppose that there you can find some proofs
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367135/why-does-the-harmonic-series-diverge-but-the-p-harmonic-series-converge