# Definition of Convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

What is the definition of convergence? The reason why I'm asking this question is to understand why $\frac1x$ diverges and $\frac1{x^2}$ converges.

The $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x=0$ as does $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{x^2}$. So why is one convergent and one divergent?

Comment: are you asking about divergence vs. convergence of the series $\Sigma \dfrac1x$ and $\Sigma \dfrac1{x^2}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes - especially seeing as they both have a finite limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the harmonic series diverge but the p-harmonic series converge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367135/why-does-the-harmonic-series-diverge-but-the-p-harmonic-series-converge)

Comment: You seem to be confusing convergence/divergence of the **sequence** $(a_n)_{1}^{\infty}$ with convergence/divergence of the **series** $\sum_{1}^{\infty} a_n$.