# Proving the convergence of the $p$-series without using the integral test?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble figuring out how to prove the convergence of the $p$-series, that is,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^p}}$$

where $p > 1$.

I'm in a real analysis course and I have a midterm coming up.  I think I might need to prove this on the midterm, but **without** using the integral test.  I appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: If you want to look for alternatives, look for the [Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)

Comment: I'm reluctant to use either of those because we haven't covered them in class.  Is there a way to show it using partial sums?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/self-contained-proof-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1np-converges-for).

Answer (score 5):

The sum from $n=2^k$ to $n=2^{k+1}-1$ is at most the number $2^k$ of terms times the largest term $1/2^{pk}$. Since $r=2^{1-p}\lt1$, the sum of the series is at most
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^p}\leqslant\sum_{k\geqslant0}\frac{2^k}{2^{pk}}=\sum_{k\geqslant0}r^k=\frac1{1-r}=\frac1{1-2^{1-p}}.
$$

Comment: Why not honor Cauchy? =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Quote: "I'm reluctant to use either of those because we haven't covered them in class. Is there a way to show it using partial sums?" Unquote.

Comment: Well, what's the difference from using it in disguise and using it?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

We have for $p\ne0$

$$\frac{1}{n^{p}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{p}}=\frac{1}{n^{p}}\left(1-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-p}\right)\sim \frac{p}{n^{p+1}}$$
and use telescoping sum.

Answer (score 1):

If $p>2$, then $\displaystyle\sum_1\frac1{n^p}<\sum_1\frac1{n^2}<1+\sum_2\frac1{n(n-1)}=2$. So the question now remains how to prove its convergence for $p\in(1,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that the partial sum from 1 to $2^N-1$ is bounded gruoping
$$a_1+(a_2+a_3)+(a_4+\cdots+a_7)+\cdots$$
and bounding with the sum of a geometric progression.