# Prove convergence for p>1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove the series is convergent for p>1:

$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(n)(ln(n)^p)}$

The ratio test is inconclusive. I assume a comparison test is involved but am not sure how to make that happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I'm assuming $n=k$ in your question and $k$ must start from 2!

Use the same reduction (combine 1 term, 2 terms, 4 terms, etc.) as in the case of the p-series, and then... you get the p-series.

See [Proving the convergence of the $p$-series without using the integral test?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661299/proving-the-convergence-of-the-p-series-without-using-the-integral-test) for the proof of the p-series.

$$
\sum_{n\geq2}\frac1{n \ln(n)^p}\leq\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{2^k}{2^k\ln(2^k)^{p}}=\frac{1}{\ln(2)^p}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k^p}.
$$

Technically you should say that the partial sums are all bounded above by the RHS.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Try integral test..........