# Question About a Proof that Shows the Covergence of p-series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In the question [Self-Contained Proof that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2k+1}\frac{1}{n^p}$ Converges for $p>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/29466/518421), joriki made a proof to show that when $p>1$, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2k+1}\frac{1}{n^p}$ converges:

> We can bound the partial sums by multiples of themselves:
>
> $$\begin{eqnarray}
> S_{2k+1}
> &=&
> \sum_{n=1}^{2k+1}\frac{1}{n^p}\\
> &=&
> 1+\sum_{i=1}^k\left(\frac{1}{(2i)^p}+\frac{1}{(2i+1)^p}\right)\\
> &<&1+\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{2}{(2i)^p}\\
> &=&1+2^{1-p}S_k\\
> &<&1+2^{1-p}S_{2k+1}\;.
> \end{eqnarray}$$
>
> Then solving for $S_{2k+1}$ yields
>
> $$S_{2k+1}<\frac{1}{1-2^{1-p}}\;,$$
>
> and since the sequence of partial sums is monotonically increasing and >bounded from above, it converges.

I understand how this proof show that when $p>1$, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2k+1}\frac{1}{n^p}$ converges and I know that when $p\leq1$, this series diverges. However, I cannot understand why when $p<1$, the series become less than a negative value shown by the proof. How does the proof get to this step as the original series can never be less than $0$? And does this proof also mean that when $p\leq1$, this series diverges because being less than a negative automatically shows divergence?

Comment: The sentence "is less than a series that is not existed" is confusing me.  Can you explain what doesn't exist?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I just deleted this sentence since mostly I am confused about the "less than a negative value" part.

Comment: You are getting an error when $p<1$ because you are dividing an inequality by a negative number. Note that $1-2^{1-p} <0$ when $p<1$. The last step in the argument is false but the previous step is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you! It is exactly the reason that made me feel confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $S_{2k+1}<1+2^{1-p}S_{2k+1},$ implying $$S_{2k+1}(1-2^{1-p})<1.$$  However,  if  $p\leq 1$ then $1-2^{1-p}\leq 0,$ and then the inequality above  yields no useful information, and does $not$ imply the last inequality of your Q.  An inequality of the form $AB<1$ with $A=S_{2k+1}>0$ and $B\leq 0$ tells us nothing more about $A.$

$S_{2k+1}$ is always positive.

A different method is needed to show divergence when $p\leq 1.$

The Cauchy Condensation Test gives a quick answer to convergence or divergence for all p.