# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+n)^z}$ for $a>0,\operatorname{Re}z>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that for $a>0$ and $\operatorname{Re}z>1$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+n)^z}$ converges.
Here's where I am.
The ratio test gives
$\lim |\frac{(a+n)^z}{(a+n+1)^z}|=\lim |\frac{a+n}{a+n+1}|^z=1$, which tells me nothing.

Hints only, please.

Comment: Your limit in question does not hold, since the limit as $n \to \infty$ is actually $1$. In general, for a rational function $P(n)/Q(n)$, when $\deg(P) = \deg(Q)$, the limit as $n\to \infty$ is the ratio of the leading coefficients of $P,Q$.

Comment: What makes you think this limit is zero? Anyway, do you know what is $|(a+n)^z|$?

Comment: Why not try the Cauchy condensation test initially? This approach is quite standard on Riemann zeta and can be used on Hurwitz zeta with some manipulation.

Comment: Yes, the limit is actually 1. Edited.

Comment: In general, $|k^z|\neq |k|^z$. The left-hand side is real, the right-hand side need not be.

Comment: I figure I'm not allowed to use the condensation test because it isn't in the textbook.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:*
$$
 \left| \frac{1}{(a+n)^z}\right| = \frac{1}{|(a+n)^z|} = \frac{1}{(a+n)^{\operatorname{Re}z}}
\le \frac{1}{n^{\operatorname{Re}z}} \, .
$$

Comment: ... and then see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29450/42969.